# How to interpret WMIC command output for CPU utilization?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cpu, wmic

When I ran below command to get overall server CPU utilization 2 times in a row, it showed 28% and 99%.
I checked both times in **Task Manager** - **Performance/Processes** and found that in processes tab 99% CPU was used by "system idle processes".

```
wmic cpu get LoadPercentage /value
```

Now the questions are:

1. Does above wmic command show CPU utilization with also including idle processes usage?
   If that is the case then why it didn't show 99% when I checked 1st time?
   I can still see idle processes using 99% CPU?
2. Why did it show 99% CPU 2nd time while all the CPU was used by idle processes only?

Comment: CPU usage is dynamic.  I'm not sure what you expect to see.

Comment: @foxidrive..simply I want to know whether "system idle processes” CPU utilisation is counted in `wmic cpu get LoadPercentage` command ?

Comment: No, I don't think it is.  You'll have to find out which core is it reporting, or if it adds all CPU cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idle process is not counted towards total load or else it would have to report always 99%. If all your programs need 50% of your CPU the other 50% are occupied by the idle process. There was probably another program running or initializing `wmic` put load on the CPU.